# Unable to find the controller for path "login_check". The route is wrongly configured

Tags: symfony, security, authentication

I am trying to configure two separate login form with two different provider, but i keep getting this error when i am trying to login to the "private_login".

Both route are configure separately and i have both SecurityController.

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    apx_firewall:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: in_memory
            login_path: /login
            check_path: /login_check
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            default_target_path: /
        logout:
            invalidate_session: true
            delete_cookies:
                REMEMBERME: { path: null, domain: null}
            path: /logout
            target: /
        remember_me:
                 secret: "%secret%"
                 lifetime: 777600 # 90 jours (en seconde)
                 path: /
                 domain: ~
        security: true
        anonymous: true

    apx_private:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            provider: apx_provider
            login_path: private_login
            check_path: private_login_check
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            default_target_path: /espace-franchises
        logout:
            invalidate_session: true
            delete_cookies:
                REMEMBERME: { path: null, domain: null}
            path: private_logout
            target: /espace-franchises
        remember_me:
                 secret: "%secret%"
                 lifetime: 777600 # 90 jours (en seconde)
                 path: /
                 domain: ~
        security: true
        anonymous: true
```

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have 2 firewalls set on the same pattern/path.

From what I get, you should be able to set the second firewall only on `/espace-franchises`. Do it, and move it first also (since first matched firewall is used).